# How can I make a (recursive) template in AngularJS when using nested objects?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, recursion, template-engine

I have the following plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7VkKbr9r1CQ2PA95826U

I want to build a  list that will represent the data in the json file.(probably recursion?)

The json can be changed as needed.
the depth of the nested items is not known,

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812909/creating-multi-level-lists-with-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the link that Nicolae Olariu gave me and managed to create what I wanted if I had the data head a time. If I got it from the server I had  a problem as mentioned in my following question:

[JSON parsing error in angularjs when getting from server but not when static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962097/json-parsing-error-in-angularjs-when-getting-from-server-but-not-when-static)