# JSON parsing error in angularjs when getting from server but not when static

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parsing, data-binding

I have this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FnCTfZf8RVBx2WVscyK8?p=info

if I change the line/s(around 23)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.links = [...];
});
```

to

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('data.json')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.links = data;
                });
```

I don't see any data.

I guess this happens because the data is set after the ui has already been rendered.
How do I make the data binding work corectlly?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jeMVdPGf2X1UW4xaIIbA?p=preview)

Comment: @Sai the data from the json is not shown.

Comment: ohh you mean the submenu object... I thought about links object which i was seeing properly.. Anyways I have updated in the answer verify. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is different reference of variables.
i.e when you say

```
a = b
```

Then when you modify "b", "a" is not going to change. Hence, in ng-init you have just initialized with value

```
submenu = links
```

When "links" gets updated then "submenu" does not.

So, here you can setup watch on scope variable "links", which when updated you can update "submenu".

Please find the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jeMVdPGf2X1UW4xaIIbA?p=preview) for the same.

Code:

```
$scope.$watch('links',function(newValue){
   $scope.submenu=newValue;
});
```